# What does .NET application setting type (Web Service URL) do?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In the Visual Studio 2022 designer for Settings.settings, one of the available Types for your setting is '(Web Service URL)'.

[image: VS2022 designer for Settings.settings]

In the generated code, the only difference compared to choosing 'string' is the addition of the `SpecialSettingAttribute` on the third line below.

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.WebServiceUrl)]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("not-a-url")]
public string HelpUrl {
    get {
        return ((string)(this["HelpUrl"]));
    }
}
```

The general [docs for application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022) mention the URL possibility but don't give any details. While the [specific docs for that VS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/settings-page-project-designer?view=vs-2022) don't say anything useful.

- What are the differences between '(Web Service URL)' and 'string'?
- Why is it *Web Service* URL, and not just URL?
- Is there a way to get the designer, or the runtime, to validate the setting actually contains a URL, and better yet, to return a `System.Uri` rather than a `string`?

Comment: Don't include too many questions in one case, it may prevent others from helping you well. I made it very clear in the answer that type just adds a specific type to the string so that it will not be polluted by other data. For validation url you can use Uri.IsWellFormedUriString.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT It's true there are multiple parts to this question, but they are closely related. I think a comprehensive answer to any part of the question will cover the others too.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT "adds a specific type to the string so that it will not be polluted by other data" appears not to be true, although I wish it were. Open the Settings design view in VS, add a (Web Service URL), and the designer will let you put any string in the Value column. And there's no exception when you access it in code via `string s = Properties.Settings.Default.MyTestUrl`.